# Call external method from AppDelegate swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui, push-notification

I implemented the three callback functions inside the AppDelegate class as suggested in the [Register Your App and Retrieve Your App's Device Token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns#2942137) example. The *didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken()* calls the *self.sendDeviceTokenToServer(data: deviceToken)* assuming that this method is within the AppDelegate class. However, I prefer *sendDeviceTokenToServer()* to belong to a different class. However, the following implementation has a runtime error: "Fatal Error: No ObservableObject of type Client found":

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct app1App: App {
  var client : Client = Client()
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MainView().environmentObject(client)
    }
  }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  @EnvironmentObject var client : Client

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
            didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
                deviceToken: Data) {
    client.sendDeviceTokenToServer(token : deviceToken)        // <<<----- this is where it crashes
  }

 }
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem? The views inside the *MainView* have no problem accessing the methods and properties of the *client* object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `@EnvironmentObject` is only for a SwiftUI `View` it does not work in a `class`
2. `@EnvironmentObject` has to be injected in the parent `View` the `AppDelegate` has no way of knowing about it.
3. One approach is to have the `AppDelegate` own  the `client` and then make is available to the subviews of the `app1App`

Remove from `app1App`

```
  var client : Client = Client()
```

Then change the `AppDelegate`

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let client : Client = Client()
    //the rest of the delegate
}
```

Then inject the `client` to the subviews by replacing

```
MainView().environmentObject(client)
```

With

```
MainView().environmentObject(appDelegate.client)
```

The `client` will be available by `appDelegate.client`

This of course assumes the the `client` is an `ObservableObject`

Comment: Your suggestion works - thank you very much. You said "One approach" - are there any alternatives? My client object is the CocoaMQTT client and I was wondering if having it inside the AppDelegate is the best practice?

Comment: @Nazar I couldn't tell you for sure, I don't use it, seems the most straight forward, abides by the single source of truth concept. Other approaches could be to make the client a singleton and have the `AppDelegate` access the singleton and then the app, but that isn't ideal for most things.There are other ways but not as clean as my original approach. If I answered your question do you mind making it with the green checkmark please.

Comment: Only if you need it in the app delegate. If not then just put it in a singleton struct like the PersistanceController.shared from the Xcode App template when Core Data is checked. Keep in mind normally we don't init networking libraries when previewing.