# I Want to Access a Property I Declared in the App Delegate in my SwiftUI App Instance

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some code in which I am trying to access a property I declared my app delegate in my SwiftUI App instance. The minimum reproducible test case looks like so:

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SomeContent()
                .environmentObject(appDelegate.$someReference)
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
      
    @StateObject var someReference = SomeReference()
      
    return true
  }
}
```

However, I am getting an error which says 'Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member '$favoritesStore''.

How can I access someReference from my SwiftUI app instance?

Edit: This question was already answered, https://stackoverflow.com/a/72766179/9231386.

Comment: It can be as simple as let someReference = SomeReference()

Comment: Move `@StateObject var someReference = SomeReference()` out of the `func application(didFinishLaunching:)`. Right now you are defining that var *inside* of the method.